# SwiftData relationship deleteRule not being consistent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have some problems with the deleteRule in SwiftData.
When deleting some parent objects, the child objects does not delete if the `deleteRule` is `.cascade`.

I have the below models:

```
@Model
final class Exercise {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \WorkoutExercise.exercise)
    var exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = [WorkoutExercise]()
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), title: String = "", exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.exercises = exercises
    }
}
```

```
@Model
final class Workout {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \WorkoutExercise.workout)
    var exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = [WorkoutExercise]()
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), title: String = "", exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.exercises = exercises
    }
}
```

```
@Model
final class WorkoutExercise {
    var id: UUID
    var exercise: Exercise?
    var workout: Workout?
    var sets: [ExerciseSet] = [ExerciseSet]()
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), exercise: Exercise, sets: [ExerciseSet] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.sets = sets
    }
}
```

```
struct ExerciseSet: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var rest: Int
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), weight: Int, reps: Int, rest: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.reps = reps
        self.rest = rest
    }
}
```

When deleting some `Exercise` object, I expect all its `exercises: [WorkoutExercise]` childs to be also deleted and then these `WorkoutExercise` type objects to be unlinked from their `workout: Workout` parent, but does not happen.
Also, when I delete some `Workout` objects, I expect all its `exercises: [WorkoutExercise]` to be deleted since the `deleteRule` is `.cascade`.

I created 3 different tabs in the app to test this by listing all `Workout`, all `WorkoutExercise` and all `Exercise` in those three different tabs in order to see what data is still available in the database after deleting some of these objects.

Does the fact that `WorkoutExercise` model is a child of both `Workout` and `Exercise` models affects the `deleteRule`?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes I assume it must be because it has two relationships and I also think it's correct that no cascade delete occurs since that would affect the other relationship. One thing to try is to prioritise one of the models say Workout and leave its delete rule as it is but move the @Relationship property wrapper from Exercise to WorkoutExercise and then define it as .nullify, then the delete rules would be chained (in my opinion) rather than conflicting and it would be interesting to see if this works.

Comment: And how do I delete all WorkoutExercise objects from Exercise? Manually one by one?

Comment: Well first try and see if my suggestion works. And yes if you do something like I suggest then you would need manually delete the objects for the other relationship.

Comment: I tried and it does not work unfortunately..

Comment: I have a similar issue with the same data structure:
Model1 - one to many - Model2 - many to one - Model3.

If I delete Model1 in a View with @Query, everything works as expected: all referenced Model2's are deleted as well and all from deleted Model2's referenced  Model3's get a null reference to the deleted Model2's.

But if I try do the same thing from within a .sheet() with a Model3 used as a parameter, it is not working properly.
The Mode1 is deleted, but this time all related Model2's get a null reference to the former Model1 and are not deleted.